# Capture access_token from facebook's server-side authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want to capture the access_token returned by this url(below)

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK

But if I HttpResponseredirect, it takes me to a blank page with access_token and expiry secs printed. I want to capture the returned access_token and use it later. Below is my code

```
def fb_return(request):
  code = request.GET.get('code')
  fb_id = settings.FB_ID
  fb_s = settings.FB_SECRET    

  url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%(id)s&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/return&client_secret=%(secret)s&code=%(code)s'%{'id':fb_id,'secret':fb_s,'code':code}
  return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to perform the request:

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%(id)s&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/return&client_secret=%(secret)s&code=%(code)s'%{'id':fb_id,'secret':fb_s,'code':code}
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

If the response is json, you can decode it like so:

```
import simplejson
json = response.read()
dict = simplejson.load(json)
```

[Here's a similar question dealing with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690723/facebook-graph-api-and-django)

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are probably easier ways to interact with Facebook:

- If you only need to do client side thing, you can use the [Facebook javascript SDK.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
- If you are creating a canvas app you can use [django-fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango).
- If you are creating a website with Facebook login, you can use [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)
- If you want server side interaction with the graph api you can use [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy)